# jQuery not running JSON API function until double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following code which is getting the current Ethereum price in USD and then converting the USD value into a user selected currency once a button is clicked. The problem is that the USD conversion isn't happening unless the button is clicked twice. I'd be grateful for another set of eyes!

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var eth_in_usd;
                var currency_rate;
                var mycurrency_to_eth;
                var currency_iso;
                var currency_name;
                var percentage_difference;
                var myrate;

                currency_iso = $("#trade_currency").val();          

                $("#trade_currency").change(function() {
                    currency_name = $("option:selected", this);
                    currency_iso = this.value;
                }); 

                $("#getrate").click(function() {

                    $.get( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD&api_key=db65a0124a5b2d123a3d257699af8146c6e6bcedafa4302d218a33b1a96eb1c7",
                    function( data ) {                  
                        eth_in_usd = data["USD"];

                        var conversion = "USD_"+currency_iso;
                        $.get( "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q="+ conversion +"&compact=ultra&apiKey=caa74f2037254dcc3adb",
                        function ( response ) {
                            currency_rate = response[conversion];
                        });                         

                        currency_rate = eth_in_usd*currency_rate;
                        $( '#eth_to_currency' ).text("The current Ethereum price is " +currency_rate+ " "+currency_iso+" (based on the average price of the top 50 exchanges by volume).");                 

                    });                 

                    percentage_difference = $("#mypercentage").val();
                    var percentage_value = mycurrency_to_eth*(percentage_difference/100)

                    myrate = parseFloat(percentage_value) + parseFloat(mycurrency_to_eth);
                    myrate = parseFloat(myrate).toFixed(2);

                    $("#myrate").text(myrate + " " + currency_iso);
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: `currency_rate = eth_in_usd*currency_rate;` and next line happen outside the inner `$.get()` call. That means they are ran before the inner $.get() is done. They should be in the callback of the inner `$.get()`

Comment: Where is the value for `mycurrency_to_eth` coming from?

Comment: $.get( "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q="+ conversion +"&compact=ultra&apiKey=caa74f2037254dcc3adb",
function ( response ) {
 currency_rate = response[conversion];
 currency_rate = eth_in_usd*currency_rate;
}); -- like this? It still gives the same result.

Comment: Ignore mycurrency_to_eth, part of something else

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are calling

```
$.get()
```

within button click event and other operations out of get call which will be async in nature. Try promise for this

```
  $("#getrate").click(function() {
    getCurrentPirce().then(function(data){
  eth_in_usd = data["USD"];

                        var conversion = "USD_"+currency_iso;
                        $.get( "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q="+ conversion +"&compact=ultra&apiKey=caa74f2037254dcc3adb",
                        function ( response ) {
                            currency_rate = response[conversion];
                        });                         

                        currency_rate = eth_in_usd*currency_rate;
                        $( '#eth_to_currency' ).text("The current Ethereum price is " +currency_rate+ " "+currency_iso+" (based on the average price of the top 50 exchanges by volume).");                 

                    percentage_difference = $("#mypercentage").val();
                    var percentage_value = mycurrency_to_eth*(percentage_difference/100)

                    myrate = parseFloat(percentage_value) + parseFloat(mycurrency_to_eth);
                    myrate = parseFloat(myrate).toFixed(2);

                    $("#myrate").text(myrate + " " + currency_iso);
  })


                    });

                    function getCurrentPirce(){
                    return new Promise(function(resolve){
                      $.get( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD&api_key=db65a0124a5b2d123a3d257699af8146c6e6bcedafa4302d218a33b1a96eb1c7",
                    function( data ) {                  
                       resolve(data);
                    });    
                    })
                    }
```

Sorry, I missed inner $.get()..

Try this ---

```
 $("#getrate").click(function() {
    getCurrentPirce().then(function(crrRate){
      currency_rate = eth_in_usd*crrRate;
      $( '#eth_to_currency' ).text("The current Ethereum price is " +currency_rate+ " "+currency_iso+" (based on the average price of the top 50 exchanges by volume).");                 
      percentage_difference = $("#mypercentage").val();
      var percentage_value = mycurrency_to_eth*(percentage_difference/100)
      myrate = parseFloat(percentage_value) + parseFloat(mycurrency_to_eth);
      myrate = parseFloat(myrate).toFixed(2);
      $("#myrate").text(myrate + " " + currency_iso);
    })
});

function getCurrentPirce(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    $.get( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD&api_key=db65a0124a5b2d123a3d257699af8146c6e6bcedafa4302d218a33b1a96eb1c7",
          function( data ) {
            eth_in_usd = data["USD"];
            var conversion = "USD_"+currency_iso;
            $.get( "https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q="+ conversion +"&compact=ultra&apiKey=caa74f2037254dcc3adb",
                  function ( response ) {
                  currency_rate = response[conversion];
            });  
      resolve(currency_rate);
    });    
  })
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. It's really hard to "follow" your script... :|

Comment: Thanks. This is giving me the same result though. I need to click the button twice. I would need the current Ethereum price in USD before changing it into another currency. Would it make sense to switch them around?

Comment: It loos like the problem is that it's not getting the default currency.

Comment: You dont need to surround jquey ajax methods in a promise, it already returns a Thenable. Also you are still calculating `currency_rate` outside of the inner $.get()

Comment: The currency_rate outside of the $.get() is for the default value which is set. I have removed that and separated the functions. I'm now calculating the final rate (myrate)when #getrate is clicked. It's working but not ideal as it would be better to have the default option value too.